How to aggregate json columns based on value in PieCloudDB
In my PieCloudDB Database I have a json column like this:



json_col




{"id": 1,"data": [{"col1": "A","col2": "B","col3": "C"}, {"col1": "D","col2": "E","col3": "F"}]}


'{"id": 2,"data": [{"col1": "G","col2": "H","col3": "I"}, {"col1": "J","col2": "K","col3": "L"}]}



I want to output it in table form with id and colx as columns.
I tried the following:
SELECT
    json_col->>'id' AS id,
    json_data.col1,
    json_data.col2,
    json_data.col3
FROM
    c,
    json_to_recordset(json_col->'data') AS json_data
    (
        col1 text,
        col2 text,
        col3 text
    )

and got this:



id
col1
col2
col3




1
A
B
C


1
D
E
F


2
G
H
I


2
J
K
L



But I want to get a result like this, grouped by id:



id
col1
col2
col3




1
A,D
B,E
C,F


2
G,J
H,K
I,L




I found a solution(Using string_agg in PieCloudDB Database):
SELECT
    json_col->>'id' AS id,
    string_agg((json_data->>'col1'), ',') AS col1,
    string_agg((json_data->>'col2'), ',') AS col2,
    string_agg((json_data->>'col3'), ',') AS col3
FROM
    c,
    json_array_elements(json_col->'data') AS json_data
GROUP BY
    id
ORDER BY
    id;

